# Distribution which has maximum or minimum variance for a given entropy

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, density-function, entropy

We know that the normal distribution has the maximum entropy among all continuous distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ for a given variance.

I wonder what's the opposite, i.e. what distribution has the maximum (or minimum) variance for a given entropy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal distribution has the maximum entropy among all continuous distributions **with fixed mean and variance** on real support.

The variance for a given entropy can be made arbitrarily large using a mixture of two Gaussians that are spread farther and farther apart.  The variance increases, while the entropy doesn't change much.

The minimum variance for a given entropy sounds the same to me as asking for the maximum entropy for a given variance, and so I think you're right that it is normal.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "for given variance" part in the question, which has been edited. My haunch for the minimum variance is the normal distribution, but i am not sure.

Comment: The entropy of the normal distribution is an increasing function of the variance. So if for a given entropy $S$ the normal distribution has a variance $V$, then for the given entropy $S$ there exists no distribution with a lower variance than $V$ because for any distribution with smaller variance than $V$ the entropy must be smaller than $S$.